# Comparing 2 csv files to remove rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pycharm

I have 2 csv files that have information related to each other. Each row of one csv file corresponds to another row in the other file. In order to prepare the data, I needed to remove certain values from the first csv file which resulted in removing certain rows from that file. Now when I print those rows out they jump around. As an example a certain portion of the first csv file jumps from row number 20838 to 20842, 20843, etc. So what I want to do is compare the first csv file that had certain rows removed to the second csv file and remove the rows that are not currently in the first csv file from the second csv file and then reorder all the rows so that both csv files have rows listed from 0 to 20000. I am using Pandas and numpy.
This is the code I have used to remove the information from the first csv file:

```
data_csv1 = pd.read_csv("address1")
data_csv2 = pd.read_csv("address2")
data_csv1.drop(data.columns[[0]], axis = 1)
data_csv1 = data_csv1[(data_csv1 !=0).all(1)]
```

How would I go about doing this? I personally do not care if the data is removed or simply ignored, I just need both csv files to contain the same row numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that at start your two files had exact same index, you can pass index of first file to the second file after post processing:

```
data_csv2 = data_csv2.iloc[data_csv1.index]
```